# How to tell ANT-exec, the location of git executable

Tags: git, unix, ant, aix

I am trying to run git clone from ANT. But seems like ANT is not able to find git executable. I have tried following options.

```
<exec executable="/opt/freeware/bin/git">

<exec executable="/usr/bin/git">

<exec executable="git">
```

Comment: What does the command `which git` say?

Answer (score 2):

A more robust option is to use the [jgit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) ANT task:

```
<project name="demo" default="clone">

  <target name="bootstrap">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/jgit.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/eclipse/jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/3.1.0.201310021548-r/org.eclipse.jgit-3.1.0.201310021548-r.jar"/>
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/jgit.ant.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/eclipse/jgit/org.eclipse.jgit.ant/3.1.0.201310021548-r/org.eclipse.jgit.ant-3.1.0.201310021548-r.jar"/>
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/jsch.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.50/jsch-0.1.50.jar"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clone">
    <taskdef resource="org/eclipse/jgit/ant/ant-tasks.properties"/>
    <git-clone uri="https://github.com/myproject/myrepo.git" dest="build/myrepo" branch="master"/>
  </target>

  <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="build"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- The "bootstrap" task will download the jgit jars. Only needs to be run once.

Answer (score 1):

you want to abstract the location into a property.

```
<property name="git.executable" value="/usr/bin/git" />
```

and then in your `exec` you specify that property

```
<exec executable="${git.executable}">
```

This will allow others to specify a different location from the commandline:

`ant -Dgit.executable=/usr/local/bin/git`
Or better yet in a `user.properties` file that is ignored by source control but imported into your build.xml

That answers your question, but I want to mention that it's like crossing the streams to put references to your source control system in your build.  You want those concerns to be separate.  The build should be source control agnostic.