# Rimersolution ANT Git plugin

Tags: git, ant, jgit

I face problem while checking out the code from Git cloud repository.

Here is the ANT build code

```
  <project name="ProjectX" default="checkoutcode" basedir="."  xmlns:git="antlib:com.rimerosolutions.ant.git">
<taskdef uri="antlib:com.rimerosolutions.ant.git"
         resource="com/rimerosolutions/ant/git/jgit-ant-lib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="./external-libs/org.eclipse.jgit.ant-3.0.0.201306101825-r.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="./external-libs/org.eclipse.jgit-3.0.0.201306101825-r.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="./external-libs/jsch-0.1.50.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="./external-libs/ant-git-tasks-0.0.1.jar"/>

       </classpath>
  </taskdef>

    <git:settings refId="git.testing"
        username="userx"
        password="passx"
        name="Rashmin"
        email="r@r.com"/>

    <target name="checkoutcode">
   <git:git directory="c:\documents\projectxsrcbuild" verbose="true" settingsRef="git.testing">
            <git:init uri="https://github.com/company/projectx.git" />
            <git:checkout branchname="development" />

        </git:git>
    </target>
     </project>
```

This is the result I get on console

```
Buildfile: C:\document\git\Platform\build\buildprojectx.xml

check:

init:
   [delete] Deleting directory c:\documents\projectxsrcbuild
    [mkdir] Created dir: c:\documents\projectxsrcbuild

checkoutcode:
[antlib:com.rimerosolutions.ant.git:checkout] The branch 'development' was not found.
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: The git "checkout" command is normally used to switch branches. Does the ANT plugin provide a "branch" command?

Comment: Here is the WIKI page I refer. The checkoutTask is only for 'checkout' while the BranchTask is for 'branch switch'. They write purpose of task in description.                   https://github.com/rimerosolutions/ant-git-tasks/wiki/CheckoutTask

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/rimerosolutions/ant-git-tasks/wiki/BranchTask

Comment: Hello I tried following, does not work for me!                                                 <git:git directory="c:\documents\projectxsrcbuild" verbose="true" settingsRef="git.testing">
   <git:init uri="https://github.com/company/projectx.git" />
   <git:branch branchname="development" force="false" settingsref="git.testing" />
   
  </git:git>

Comment: A bit late, but still the wiki pages should have helped. The "checkout" task has an optional "createbranch" attribute which defaults to "false".

Answer (score 0):

I'm more familiar with [JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) which has an associated ant task.

- [jGit ANT task](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide#Ant_Tasks)

Also available from Maven Central repository:

- ["org.eclipse.jgit.ant" artefact in Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22org.eclipse.jgit.ant%22)

Not entirely clear what your ANT task is, although looking at the jar dependencies, looks like it too depends on JGit.

Examples of my ANT usage of JGit:

1. [How to tell ANT-exec, the location of git executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195407/how-to-tell-ant-exec-the-location-of-git-executable/20205861#20205861)
2. [How can I get the latest commit ID of the currently checked out branch in git, using ANT, without having an active git installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14401711/how-can-i-get-the-latest-commit-id-of-the-currently-checked-out-branch-in-git-u/14411133#14411133)

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried using jGit, but if failed at connecting my repository. I mean failed at authentication. My Repo is HTTPS and requires authentication.